# Search For Exact Match In JSON With JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, for-loop, nested-for-loop

I have been trying to figure out how have a form submit which then checks all the data in the form against JSON array data to determine if an object which matches all the input is already present. To start, here is my sample JSON data:

```
[
{
    "ASIN":"B0971Y6PQ3",
    "price":"13.99",
    "email": "test@gmail.com"
},
{
    "ASIN":"B077TLGP58",
    "price":"13.99",
    "email":"test@gmail.com"
}
]
```

So I am trying to run a for loop which will test whether all the form data already exists as a JSON object. Here's what I currently have:

```
// Check to see if it's already in asinJSON.json
for(i=0; i<asinJSON.length;i++){
    if(asinJSON[i].email == email){
        // Email is already in json
        if(asinJSON[i].ASIN == inputVal){
            // Email && ASIN are already in json
            if(asinJSON[i].price == desiredPrice){
                // Email, ASIN, Price all match. Duplicate.
                console.log('same price found. product already exists.');
                break;
            }
            // If price doesn't match, user wants to update price
            console.log('updating price');
            // Update price here
            // updateJSON();
            break;
        }
        // Existing user wants to add new product.
        console.log('product not found');
        // Insert product for existing user
        // createAndAdd();
        break;
    }
    // New user wants to add a product.
    console.log('email not found.');
    // insert product for new user
    // createAndAdd();
    break;
}
```

How it is now, when trying to test whether it can find the second object, it console.logs "product not found," which I understand is because it passes the first if statement but fails the second with the 1st object in the JSON array.

I'm also assuming it has to do with my break statements, and that something is wrong there. I've also tried return statents and haven't been able to figure it out. I've been self-taught so there are, unfortunately, some things that I have definitely missed along the way. But, I have looked aroung Google and StackOverflow and haven't really been able to find an answer, so here I am.

I'm ready to be schooled in how this logic should be set up to get it to work properly. I appreciate all the feedback in advance!

Comment: You're printing `not found` whenever the first array element doesn't match. And you're breaking after doing that, so you never continue looking for a matching element.

Comment: ^ use `continue` instead of `break` and the existing code should work fine

Answer (score 0):

Use the `find()` method to search for a matching element.

```
if (asinJSON.find(({ASIN, price, email: json_email}) => 
    ASIN == inputVal && price == desiredPrice && json_email == email)) {
    console.log("product already exists");
} else {
    console.log("product not found");
}
```

Comment: Ahh. Thank you so much Barmar. I saw find() when I was looking for a solution, but got put off by the fact that it only returns the first element that matches. I was misguidedly thinking about using it INSIDE the for loop, as opposed to INSTEAD of the for loop. I will give that a try. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

There are many options, one easy one is to use lodash

```
const email = <email to find>
const price = <price to find> (however, keep your mind around floating points comparison here...)
const ASIN = < ASIN to find >
if (findIndex(asinJSON, { ASIN, price, email }) > -1) {
   // found
}
```